# How to enforce insert with specific field?

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(
  id INT NOT NULL, 
  timestamp TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,
  data BLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I can insert on it with:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (timestamp, data) VALUES
                        ('2014-07-11 11:25:48.185', LOAD_FILE('sql/file.bin'));
```

In the above insert I was not enforced to insert the `id` field.

How may I create the table (`my_table`) so that it prevents inserts without `id`?

I would every insert to be made (providing the `id`) like, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, timestamp, data) VALUES
                        (7, '2014-07-11 11:25:48.185', LOAD_FILE('sql/file.bin'));
```

I was thinking `NOT NULL` was there for it.

Comment: why not define id as AUTO_INCREMENT ?

Comment: There is another table with AUTO_INCREMENT id, that table when triggered inserts on this one. Here I just want to prevent inserts without id.

Comment: you have id not null ... this should raise an error if you insert without id ... what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent inserts with an empty value for `ID` (or not value passed), simply define the column as `NOT NULL` as you defined it.

I can't see how your example worked (i.e. inserting only into `(timestamp, data)`).

Now, the fact that there is another table with a trigger that inserts in this one does not have any effect on the `ID` column of this table. If you define it as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, whenever you insert a new row, the ID will automatically get a new value which will be fully independent from any data of the first table.

You can have as many tables as you wish with auto-incremented fields, each running a different sequence (and hence their numbering will be fully independent).

To summarize:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(
  id        INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT               , 
  timestamp TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ,
  data      BLOB             NULL                              ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  );
```

Comment: Which tool do you use/recommend to align columns?

Comment: @KcFnMi are you sure you are not confused and posted a comment aimed for another question?

Comment: No, it's a side question. I tough your SQL is nicely aligned.

Comment: Ah @KcFnMi, thanks! No, I don't use any tool but my fingers. Long ago I became used to write my code that would make it easy for me (and others) to read. Yes, it is a little bit more tedious, but it largely pays off (at least in my opinion).

Comment: Cool. I'm experimenting with Sublime AlignTab (https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab). I would like to know how to imitate you via Sublime AlignTab (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787620/align-mysql-in-fdavidov-style).

Comment: @KcFnMi, I use Notepad++ (yes, old but great!) with some changes from default. For instance, I change that TAB character will never be used and, instead, it fills the **correct** space with blanks, making my code's alignment independent of the editor other people uses. It also has other great features line rectangular selection/copy/paste, multi-lines typing, a huge list of known languages (and hence shows keywords colored), etc... Last, you may wish to try it and, most probably, you will like it.

Comment: @KcFnMi, by the way, did my answer (to your original question) helped? If yes, I'd appreciate if you can up-vote it and mark it as such (click on the "V").

Comment: I'm particularly interested on how the NULL / NOT NULL were aligned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128968/discussion-between-fdavidov-and-kcfnmi).

Comment: Simply typing spaces.

Comment: Well, I think that's the point. I would like to automate this space typing step via Sublime (ideally). Could you automate it on Notepad++?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I know that you can develop plug-ins, so there you have a challenge: develop a **configurable** aligner and post it at Notepad++ site (like many other plug-ins there), and don't forget to post a message here when done so I pick it up :-) !!!

Comment: By the way, if you have set (Notepad++) tab size = 4 and use spaces, you would get the above result with the sequence: `<tab>NOT<tab>NULL<enter><tab><tab>NULL` (`NOT` has 3 letters!!). Try it...